# Who has scored the most goals as a substitute?

Tags: football, trivia, english-premier-league

EPL has had quite a few prolific super-subs (from [Solksjaer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ole_Gunnar_Solskj%C3%A6r) to probably [Chicharito](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javier_Hern%C3%A1ndez_Balc%C3%A1zar) today). Who has scored the most goals as a substitute in the EPL?

<sub>Note: If statistics aren't available since 1991, feel free to give an answer from the year of availability of statistics</sub>

---

Also, who has scored the most winners as a substitute?

Comment: I would be interested to see these stats on a goals per game basis too. Chicharito, [Džeko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edin_D%C5%BEeko), et al., of the "modern" era have been making a name for being very potent, off-the-bench scorers.

Answer (score 4):

[Jermain Defoe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jermain_Defoe) has scored the most Premier League goals with 20 off the bench. This is followed by [Kanu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nwankwo_Kanu) and [Solksjaer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ole_Gunnar_Solskj%C3%A6r) with 17 each.

-[Source](http://talksport.com/magazine/features/120710/which-subs-have-scored-most-goals-premier-league-history-find-out-here-176307?p=4).

Comment: Seems like a good answer to me. My bet for the most winners would be on Solskaer though